# Login to AzureSQL via JDBC using authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword

Tags: jdbc, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, java-11

I created a AzureAD User svcDBadmin using authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword in Java - Maven with the below pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.jre11-preview</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am using JDK 11 and getting this error

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Failed to authenticate the user svcDBadmin@svc.emccloud.com in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword).
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthToken(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:71)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getFedAuthToken(SQLServerConnection.java:4446)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.onFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:4419)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.processFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:4384)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onFedAuthInfo(tdsparser.java:289)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:125)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5237)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3992)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3936)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7377)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3210)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2717)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2363)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2214)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1275)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:861)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
at Hello.main(Hello.java:20)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthToken(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:69)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthToken(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:63)
... 19 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am not able to find any Example in Azure nor their Git page

Anyone faced this issue, if you share how to solve it, will be helpful

P.S: I started using adalj but for JDK 11, it told to use - https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java#update-to-msal4j-now